# idioma por defecto en movil

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aplicación-movil, idioma, i18n

tengo una pagina **multi-idioma**, antes ponia por defecto el idioma en español y lo cambiaba y lo guardaba en el local mediante botones.
Ahora tenia que coger el **idioma por defecto del navegador e inicializarlo**
.
Lo he probado en el **pc y funciona correctamente, pero en el mvl no** coge el idioma del navegador.

window.navigator.language no sirve para movil?

dejo aqui el codigo que he utilizado, gracias!

Lo hago con la libreria i18N y el contexto, el contexto es:

```
function IdiomProvider({ children }) {
    let idioma = localStorage.getItem('idioma')
    const txtnav=(window.navigator.language).substring(0,2)
    const idiomState = useState( idioma !=  null ? idioma : txtnav)
    console.log(txtnav)
    console.log(idioma)

    return (
       
            <IdiomContext.Provider value={idiomState}>
                {children}
            </IdiomContext.Provider>
      
    )


}

export default IdiomProvider
```

```
lo inicializo en el index.js asi:

const txtnav=(window.navigator.language).substring(0,2)
console.log(txtnav)
let idioma = localStorage.getItem('idioma')
i18next.init({
    interpolation: { escapeValue: false },
    lng:  idioma != null ? idioma : txtnav,
    resources: {
        es: {
            global: global_es,
        },
        pt: {
            global: global_pt,
        }, 
        gl: {
            global: global_gl,
        },
        en: {
            global: global_en,
        }         
    },
})
```

como podria **inicializarlo en mvl** al idioma que este tenga predefinido?

Comment: ¿Qué es mvl? ¿Qué resultado te da `window.navigator.language` en ese caso?

Comment: un dispositivo movil,

Comment: en el caso del pc me da "es", "gl", "pt", depende del idioma que tenga el navegador por defecto y en el mvl me da null

Comment: "es" da tras hacer el substring, supongo que antes tendrás algo como "es_ES". ¿Puedes mirar los valores en `window.navigator.languages` (con s al final)?

Comment: dependiendo en el navegador que lo mire, por ejemplo en este que estoy me da: Array [ "es" ]
​

Comment: pero en el pc no tengo ningun problema, lo coge bien, es cuando miro la web desde el mvl, que no me coge el idioma por defecto

Comment: Por eso pregunto qué es lo que obtienes al usar en un móvil en esos campos

Comment: yo entre a codepen.io e hice la prueba con chrome y safari (en mi smartphone), en ambos me arrojó "es-419" (window.navigator.language). Sería útil que puedas hacer la misma prueba con el móvil en cuestión. De todos modos te dejo este link para comprobar compatibilidad https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.language

Comment: siempre puedes intentar `navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage`